# style cdata in xml

Tags: xml, styles

Is it possible to use styles in cdata? I need to give a line break after "Something Disclaimer!" in description. Is it even possible to make "Something Disclaimer!" bold?

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<listings>
<house>
    <owner>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <website>http://www.mysite.com</website>
    </owner>
    <address>
        <street>1 place</street>
        <city>Los Angeles</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <postal_code>91011</postal_code>
        <country>USA</country>
    </address>
    <description><![CDATA[Something Disclaimer! blah blah blah]]></description>
</house>
```

Comment: What language are you styling with?

Comment: What is the rule you want to try to style? "If any text matches "Somthing Disclaimer!" then make it blue"? (While not styling "blah blah blah")?

Comment: Sorry, never used styles in an XML document before so I am not sure what you mean by language. The text will always be the same "Something Disclaimer!", give it a line break make it bold and following text will not have any styles. Also, it will be always in the description field.

Answer (score 1):

CSS operates (with the exception of [pseudo-things](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements), which won't help here) solely on **elements**, not arbitrary pieces of text.

CDATA sections are completely transparent to CSS.

So, no. It isn't possible. You would have to modify the markup first.

Comment: I don't know enough about XSL to comment.